# Angular : $state.go in $stateChangeSuccess after $http call freezes the app

Tags: angularjs

When make a `$http.get` request within my `run` method in `stateChangeSuccess` and redirect to a state, the app freezes. The app does not run into a loop, rather freezes.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {

    $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: '/some/api/endpoint',
    }).then(function(response) {
        // proceed with next route
    }, function(response) {
        $state.go('myNewState', {}, {reload: true});
    });
});
```

Any idea why?

Comment: If this request always fails and you're going as a result to the same state, and then running again this failing request, and then redirecting to the same state and then running again the failing request.........

Answer (score 0):

In additional to my comment - If the request is failing you're redirecting to `myNewState` and then run the same request again and again because of the circular state changes.

Try adding this before the request:

```
if( toState.name == 'myNewState' ) {
    return;
}
```

This will not trigger this request if you redirect the user to `myNewState`